# Fantasy Anime. Protagonist has two enemies turned allies

Tags: story-identification, anime

I don't remember the features of the protagonist only that he is a boy. He has two enemies (as far as I remember) turned allies. The first ally has a bracelet that looks like a cylinder of a revolver which he uses to attack (it flies and he can control it) he also has a red scarf and for some reason I associate him with the lotus flower. The second one has wings and his power is lightning.

Comment: When did you see it? Where was it shown and in what language?

Comment: I seen it I think around early 2000's, it was in the Philippine TV so it is most probably Filipino dub.